# fancybox no navigation buttons for video gallery, but its working in fiddle

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying for fancy box with youtube video, i came through this fiddle(added in comment) , this fiddle i got from stack over flow only by @JK . Its working fine in the fiddle, but when i copied the and apply the same in my application, the navigation button functionality is not there, and the back ground light box  is missing. Im quite new to the jquery. 
the following is my html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />  
       <TITLE> New Document </TITLE> 
       <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus"> 
       <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
       <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT=""> 
       <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
       <script> 
          $(".fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
             openEffect  : 'none',
             closeEffect : 'none',
             nextEffect  : 'none',
             prevEffect  : 'none', 
             padding     : 0, 
             margin      : 50    });
      </script>
      <script type="text/css">
        .fancybox-nav {
            width: 60px;
          }
        .fancybox-nav span {
            visibility: visible;
          }
        .fancybox-next { 
            right: -60px;
          }
     </script>
   </HEAD>
  <BODY>
     <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1&wmode=opaque">Video #1</a><br />
     <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cYplvwBvGA4?autoplay=1&wmode=opaque">Video #2</a> 
  </BODY>
 </HTML>`
```

Am i missing anything ?

Comment: this is the fiddle i reffered http://jsfiddle.net/fhpZ5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you either need more coffee or more sleep hours ;)

This :

```
  <script type="text/css">
    .fancybox-nav {
        width: 60px;
      }
    .fancybox-nav span {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    .fancybox-next { 
        right: -60px;
      }
 </script>
```

Should be :

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .fancybox-nav {
        width: 60px;
      }
    .fancybox-nav span {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    .fancybox-next { 
        right: -60px;
      }
 </style>
```

... if you can see the difference.

Additionally, it would be a good idea to wrap your custom fancybox script inside the `.ready()` method like

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
         openEffect  : 'none',
         closeEffect : 'none',
         nextEffect  : 'none',
         prevEffect  : 'none', 
         padding     : 0, 
         margin      : 50    
      });
   });
  </script>
```

Notice that I added `type="text/javascript"` to the `script` tag, since the `DOCTYPE` you are using requires that.

Comment: In IE 9, its directly going to youtube site. The light box effect is not coming

Comment: @user2502314 - check for js errors and your doctype ... or share a link and I could tell you faster what is breaking your code